# Can we superimpose a image over splash screen

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, splash-screen, screen-orientation

I am developing an ionic app. I have splash screen in android according to device to pixel ratio. Now the view which comes after the splash screen needs to be superimposed over splash screen. 
So I have written media query according to device to pixel ratio. For this I have written media queries as

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .login-background {
   background: url(images/screen_white_bg_hdpi.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: center center; 
   background-attachment: fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: 100%;
   } 
}
```

On hdpi screens this media query is working fine but for xhdpi, xxhdpi it is not working.

And can anyone tell how I should do this for the iOS app also?